Is there a way to restrict users to only see children of a parent element they belong to in Django Rest?
I have built a Django REST app for a client that allows users to join communities. The Community model has 20+ models that link back to it in some way (things like events, event dates, meetings, messages etc). I need a way to restrict users to only being able to perform CRUD operations on elements belonging to communities they are a part of. For example if user "John Smith" is a member of the "Animal Rescue Volunteers" community, he should only be able to read messages for that community and should not be able to create/edit messages in other communities.
I have seen people use the get_queryset method of a ViewSet to restrict RUD processes like so:
class MessageView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Message.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
       return self.queryset.filter(message__community__in=self.request.user.communities)

However this doesn't solve the problem with Creates and needs to be applied to each ViewSet to work. Is there a better way to do this?
UPDATE:
A developer has suggested creating an Abstract Model and having all children inherit that model like so:
class CommunityChildModel(models.Model):
    parent_community_id = models.IntegerField()
    
    class Meta:
        abstract=True

Each model that inherits from CommunityChildModel would need to set the community ID that it belongs to on save. This would then be used to filter objects for RUD operations in the ViewSet for every model using:
def get_queryset(self):
       return self.queryset.filter(parent_community_id__in=self.request.user.communities)

This can be added to an abstract viewset that others inherit from to apply this logic to all ViewSets.

what about using validation in View? like if CommunityUser.objects.filter(community_id=request.data.get("community_id", user=request.user).exists():
